# Why always got NullPointerException while getting KEY_FRAME_RATE from MediaCodec?

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec

I want to retrieve the frameRate from the `MediaCodec`, but i always got the `NullPointerException`. The code as following:

```
    public void handleWriteSampleData(MediaCodec encoder, int trackIndex, int bufferIndex, ByteBuffer encodedData, MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo) {
        super.writeSampleData(encoder, trackIndex, bufferIndex, encodedData, bufferInfo);
        int rc = -1;

        if (((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0)) {
            if (VERBOSE) Log.i(TAG, "handling BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG for track " + trackIndex);
            if (trackIndex == VIDEO_TRACK_INDEX) {
                // Capture H.264 SPS + PPS Data
                Log.d(TAG, "Capture SPS + PPS");

                captureH264MetaData(encodedData, bufferInfo);
                mFFmpeg.setVideoCodecExtraData(videoConfig, videoConfig.length);
                fps = encoder.getOutputFormat().getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE);
                Log.i(TAG, "fps:" + fps);
            }
            ....
```

The exception as following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1419): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1419):    at android.media.MediaFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.java:282)
```

I have gone through the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaFormat.java):

```
/**
 * Returns the value of an integer key.
 */
public final int getInteger(String name) {
    return ((Integer)mMap.get(name)).intValue();
}
```

How to get the right fps value from `MediaCodec` ?

Comment: don't know your code, but what if ((Integer)mMap.get(name)) returns null?
most likely, there's your problem. Have you run a debugger?

Comment: Can you show a little more of your code?

Comment: Maybe it's my problem. I'm debugging. I want to get some suggestions about retrieving the fps value from mediacodec. @Stultuske

Comment: @Sebastian Sure. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is not available from MediaCodec, because timing information is not necessarily present in H.264 (see e.g. [this link](http://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/the-h-264-sequence-parameter-set/)).  KEY_FRAME_RATE is an argument for the encoder.

A nominal frame rate value may be present in the wrapper (e.g. .mp4) that MediaExtractor handles, but I don't know if there's a consistent way to access that.

You can dig through SPS, or calculate an fps value by looking at the presentation time stamps on a series of frames.  If the video uses a variable frame rate, like "screenrecord" output does, then you may get an incorrect number from this... but I would argue that, for VFR video, there is no correct number for The Frame Rate, just maximum and average values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED flag if you want to read the MediaFormat from the Codec.

```
int bufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(this.mBufferInfo, QUEUEING_TIMEOUT);
if (bufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
    MediaFormat mMediaFormat = mMediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
}
```

Comment: As your suggestion, `Log.i(TAG, "KEY_FRAME_RATE:" + newFormat.containsKey(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE));`, i got false.

Comment: You might have to parse the framerate out of the csd-0 and csd-1 then, or just calculate it by looking at the presentation timestamps.